# Mocking UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, moq

I have the following code:

```
var clientId = this.UserManager.FindById(this.User.Identity.GetUserId()).ClientId;
```

and it is a part of one of the controllers in my app. Now I am writing unit tests and should go through this thing in order to test the actual properties of the controller.

The problem is that it throws a null reference exception because `UserManager.FindById` returns `null`. If I can mock this, so it has a property called ClientId, I will be able to avoid the exception.

What have I tried?
First mocking the UserManager itself:

```
  var fakeUserManager = new Mock<ApplicationUserManager>();
  fakeUserManager.Setup(x => x.FindById(It.IsAny<string>()))
  .Returns(user);
```

But when I try to set my controller.UserManager to it:

```
controller.UserManager = fakeUserManager.Object;
```

Visual Studio says that UserManager could not be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible.

I decided to create a user by using the UserManager, but the create method again results  in a null reference exception.

This is how the ApplicationUserManager get set up:

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
```

Solution:

Thanks to @mason answer I was able to solve the problem. I will post the solution as an edit because there are certain things in the solution that were not included in both question and answer.
First, as @mason suggested I made the setter of the UserManager property public.

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }

          set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
```

Second, and this is the different part. I was able to create a new `ApplicationUserManager` and pass it a user by mocking the `IUserStore`:

```
var store = new Mock<IUserStore<User>>(MockBehavior.Strict);

            store.As<IUserStore<User>>()
            .Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(user);

var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(store.Object);
```

Then, I just set the controller.UserManager:

```
controller.UserManager = manager;
```

Remark:
The `user` variable helps me to pass a user that has a ClientId to the controller.

Comment: How does the `UserManager` property in the controller get set up in the first place? Via a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the UserManager property because you made the setter private. Make it public.

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

Now you'll be able to set your controller's UserManager property.

Comment: Great answer, in combination with some other changes I managed to make it work, but I have a few questions. Is it good to make the store public? Is it a bad practice? And is it going to affect the security of the app?

Comment: @StefanL19 Public and private are [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx). They are not security features. They're intended to assist you in constructing a library that only exposes the features necessary so that you don't accidentally misuse the code. It's an organizational thing, not a security feature.